# merge two Where with AND in zend 2

Tags: merge, zend-framework2, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have problem to merge two conditions in my query

```
public function GetInbox($user_id , $line_number = false , $seeall = false , $limit = 0,$SearchWhere = null)
{
    if(!$SearchWhere)
        $SearchWhere = new Where();

    if(!$seeall)
    {
        $UsersLineTable = new UsersLinesTable($this->adapter);
        $UsersLine = $UsersLineTable->fetchAll(array('user_id = ?' => $user_id,'owner_type = ?' => '1'));
        if(!$UsersLine) return false;

        $SearchWhere2 = new Where();
        foreach ($UsersLine as $key => $value) { 
            $SearchWhere2->equalTo("recipient_number",$value['line_number'])
                  ->or
                  ->equalTo("recipient_number",'98'.$value['line_number'])
                 ->or;
        }

        $Select = new Select();
        $Select->where($SearchWhere2);
        $Select->where($SearchWhere);
        if($limit)
            $Select->limit($limit);
        $Select->order("receive_date DESC"); 
        $MessageProvidersInboxTable = new MessageProvidersInboxTable($this->adapter);
        return $MessageProvidersInboxTable->fetchBySelect($Select);
    }else{
        $MessageProvidersInboxTable = new  MessageProvidersInboxTable($this->adapter);
        return $MessageProvidersInboxTable->fetchAll($SearchWhere);
    }
}
```

$SearchWhere is a Where class,
$SearchWhere2 is second conditions

In this case

```
$Select->where($SearchWhere2);
$Select->where($SearchWhere);
```

$select just contain $SearchWhere conditions.

I want this query

```
Where condition1 AND (condition2)
```

is that important that condition2 contain conditions include OR operand.
Sincerely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work. Writing without looking at zend\db code:

```
$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where;

$where->addPredicate($SearchWhere, $where::OP_AND);
$where->addPredicate($SearchWhere2, $where::OP_AND);

$select->where($where);
```

Basically, `Where` object is a subclass of `Predicate`. So it should work as any other predicate.

Comment: Thanks,This is other way $select->where($SearchWhere);
$select->addPredicate($SearchWhere2);

Comment: other way will not work as you expect `where = a or b` and `where2 = c` will give `a or b and c` and you need `(a or b) and c`

Comment: I trace mysql queries and it works for my case where1 AND (where2)

Comment: i am talking about `a or b and (where2)` -> `a or (b and (where2))`